# is red black tree in kernel not protected?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, red-black-tree

In Linux kernel, to store the memory regions of a process, Linux uses both a linked list and a red-black tree. [find_vma](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c?v=2.4.37#L681) is a function which locates the first memory region whose vm_end field is greater than the passed address through red black tree. However, I find it there is has no protection (like a lock) for the red black tree inside find_vma(). What if another thread calls [rb_erase](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/rbtree.c?v=2.4.37#L223) function to delete some element on the tree at the same?

Comment: Isn't it managed through RCU?

Comment: It seems that `find_vma` itself should be called with some protection from concurrent access(modification). @Joe: Unlike to lists, rb-tree cannot be protected by RCU.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply. I agree with you. For example, in [sys_msync](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=2.4.37#L2381)  (the system call of `msync`), it calls  `down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem)` first and then `find_vma`. Does this protect the red black tree?

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your reply. Could you please give some reference for supporting your idea?

Comment: @Tsyvarev why can't rb-tree be protected by rcu locks ?

Comment: @Haswell: You may try to implement rb-tree protection via RCU, so it could possible to run "find" **concurrently** with "insert" or "delete". Note, that "find" is expected to find the element if it is not currently being inserted or being deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , find_vma function call is protected from concurrent access via semaphore.
In scheduler also function is used with semaphore calls.

```
        2209         down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
        2210         vma = find_vma(mm, start);
        ....
                     up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);



    mmap_sem is used to protect this function call which is a read-write semaphore.
    struct rw_semaphore mmap_sem; defined inside struct mm_struct.
```